# Change client URL without requesting route to Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

My router.js, which is in public directory works the following way:

First, listens to the event of clicking an 'a' tag
Then, prevents following the link and passes the href value to this function

```
function loadPage(targetUrl) {
    if (targetUrl == "/") {
        loadHome(); //Loads Home Page
    } else {
        if (isSpanish()) {
            var direction = "/pages/es" + targetUrl + ".html";
        } else {
            var direction = "/pages/en" + targetUrl + ".html";
        }
        var subDirections = direction.split("/");

        $('#content').load(direction, function (response, status, xhr) { //Loads content
            if (status == "error") {
                $("#error-popup").slideDown();
                $("#error-popup-wrapper").fadeIn();

                document.title = "404" + titleAddon;
            } else {
                document.title = document.getElementById("title").innerHTML + titleAddon;
                window.history.pushState({ url: "" + targetUrl + "" }, null, targetUrl);
            }
        });

        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
};
```

But I believe is conflicting with my index.js which controlls the only route I have:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/views/index.html'));
});
```

Everytime I click on a link, I believe the client is requesting the server for the route, and my router.js loads it correctly, but I don't want the page to reload.

How could I solve this?

P.D. Sometimes the page doesn't reload, generally when clicking the menu links. Not sure why.

The website I'm uploading this code to is: https://testing.fsupv2017.webs.upv.es

Comment: Looks like you're trying to achieve a SPA (Single Page Application) architecture. Have you considered using React, Angular or Vue for this purpose? Not that you have to, but they essentially do what you're attempting to accomplish here.

Comment: Yes, my objective is to build an SPA, but without using a Framework.